# Cost of UK Wind Power

Tags: energy-economics

I am looking for *reliable* information on the cost of wind power.  Is there any source which, ideally:

- Relates to wind power in the UK.
- Is recent – say within the last 5 years.
- Is published in a peer-reviewed academic journal.
- Is independent (not published or sponsored by an industry body or
  campaign group with a pro- or anti- wind agenda).
- Focuses on *costs* (not on auction strike prices which may or may not povide good
  evidence of costs).
- Focuses on *levelised* costs including maintenance and repair costs (not just initial capital costs).
- Is supported by evidence on the economic life of wind turbines (not just round number
  assumptions like 20 years).
- Distinguishes between costs of onshore and offshore wind.
- Makes clear whether or not its cost estimates take account of electricity system costs arising from the intermittency of wind power?

However, sources meeting most but not all those criteria would also be of interest.

Some sources I have looked at which are interesting but don’t quite meet all the criteria:

- Jansen, Staffell et al (2020) (in Nature Energy but accessed [here](https://backend.orbit.dtu.dk/ws/portalfiles/portal/242009698/Jansen_et_al_2020_competitiveness_offshore_AAM_with_Graphs.pdf)) seems to focus on auction strike prices rather than costs.
- Thomson & Harrison (2015) (accessed [here](https://www.pure.ed.ac.uk/ws/portalfiles/portal/19730442/Main_Report_Life_Cycle_Costs_and_Carbon_Emissions_of_Offshore_Wind_Power.pdf)) includes (p 18) cost estimates from a number of studies, but is a little old and not in an academic journal.
- [Hughes (2020)](https://www.ref.org.uk/Files/performance-wind-power-uk.pdf) appears to be supported by statistical analysis applied to a large database, but is published by the Renewable Energy Foundation, a body which some view as a campaign group against wind energy (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Renewable_Energy_Foundation)).